# SeeTestCloud SaaS Registration for Appium Studio

Tags: appium

I am using Appium Studio Community Edition for last 6 months; recently it is showing a dialog for **SeeTestCloud SaaS Registration**.  Unable to use the Appium Studio without registration.

[image]

While trying to do registration process it is always showing error at email address filed like below. How to resolve the problem or how to keep continue free use of community edition?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If any one face this issue please avoid gmail, yahoo, and outlook email address for SeeTestCloud SaaS Registration. I have completed it by using gmx email id.